# Compiler says there is a memory leak, but I don't see one

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

So I did that thing with Xcode where you say analyze and it finds leaks and stuff and here, it says that I am leaking (marked in code below).

```
// Copy dictionary to memory
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DataCategoriesDictionary" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dataCategoriesDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
self.choices = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[dataCategoriesDictionary objectForKey:self.chosenCategory]]; // LINE 55
[dataCategoriesDictionary release]; // HERE, the compiler says "Potential leak of an object allocated on line 55"
```

Even though it doesn't make any sense that I could be leaking a instance variable, I tried adding a release statement for it anyway and Xcode still gave me the same error. What else could I be leaking?

Comment: you double click on that line(analyzing issue line), it will show you why it is saying so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If choices is a property with retain you are leaking the NSMutableDictionary.

```
[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary
```

Either autorelease or use a temporary.

```
self.choices = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[dataCategoriesDictionary objectForKey:self.chosenCategory]] autorelease];
```

or (my favorite)

```
self.choices = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[dataCategoriesDictionary objectForKey:self.chosenCategory];
```

or

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[dataCategoriesDictionary objectForKey:self.chosenCategory]];
self.choices = tempDict;
[tempDict release];
```

Comment: For maximum simplicity, use the convenience constructor `+dictionaryWithDictionary:`!

Comment: Less code is always better, I added that as an option.  Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Or `[choices release];` followed by `choices = [[NS.. alloc] init...];`  (Substitute whatever the real instance variable name is for "choices" in the statements.)

Comment: If choices is a property, it really looks like it is, it is really best to use the setters/getters and not subvert the property ivar management.  The exceptions being init and dealloc.

Answer (score 1):

`choices` looks like a [Declared Property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html). It seems that you'd declared it like below:

In .h file:
`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *choices;`

In .m file:
`@synthesize choices`

In this case, the compiler automatically provides the setter method:

```
-(void) setChoices:(NSMutableDictionary*)newValue
{
    if (choices != newValue) {
        [choices release];
        choices = [newValue retain];
    }
}
```

From your code, `self.choices` implicitly calls setChoices method. So newly allocated NSMutableDictionary's retain count become 2 not 1, result in object leak.

Answer (score -2):

You should be releasing the member variable (ivar) that the property `choice` refers to. So assuming there is a member variable `_choice` then releasing it like this:

```
[_choice release]
```

should work.

Alternatively, if you rewrote it like this it might make it clearer why there is a leak:

```
NSMutableDictionary * temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[dataCategoriesDictionary 
self.choices = temp
[temp release]
```

Comment: If choice is a property do not release, assigning to the property does a release on the current value and a retain on the new value.  Later when the assign is done and there is a release of the current value there will be an over release.

Comment: @CocoaFu: I don't follow. I don't see where the extra release would occur?

Comment: @CocoaFu: It's correct to release the member variable since since that will update the release count correctly.See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577453/acceptable-ways-to-release-a-property