# Why "alloc" a global variables should be autorelease

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, memory-management

A simple memory management problem as below:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    ......
    self.label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];
    ......
}
```

I think label is a global variable, according to the management protocol, if you create a instance with "alloc", you should just "dealloc" it, why "autorelease" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];
```

versus

```
UILabel *temp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
self.label = temp;
[temp release];
```

are essentially the same as far as proper memory management goes.  The memory will be properly cleaned up, just at different times.

I would assume that the property of that label would be something like `@property(nonatomic,retain)` so the label continues to exist since it was retained by the property when you call `self.label`.

Comment: These are far from the same. In the second snippet, what if setLabel: makes a copy? Now you've leaked the label from `[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame]`, then overreleased the label in your instance variable. Always be careful to release exactly what you intend to release!

Comment: Would you not need to release the label again in `dealloc` if the property was a `retain` or `copy`?  Using the second line would give it a retain count of 1 after the code executed--one for the alloc and one from the property call minus one from the release.

Comment: If your property was not `retain` or `copy` before, then the first variant would have been overreleased. But yes, if your property is marked `retain` or `copy`, you have to `release` it in dealloc if you're not using ARC.
To get the second pattern correct, you'd do
`UILabel *someLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
self.label = someLabel;
[someLabel release];`

Comment: Just for everyone's reference, this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577453/acceptable-ways-to-release-a-property covers this topic of releasing properties pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

> I think label is a global variable...

No, `label` is a property of the class that contains the code you posted as evidenced by the `self.label` syntax. It's backed up by an instance variable, either explicitly declared or not. The setter for the `label` property is responsible for making sure that the value passed in is appropriately retained. The code that allocates the UILabel, `-viewDidLoad`, is responsible for releasing it, which the call to `autorelease` does.

> ...according to the management protocol, if you create a instance with
>   "alloc", you should just "dealloc" it...

That's incorrect. You never call `-dealloc` directly -- always call `-release` or `-autorelease` when you're done using an object that you created. Please see the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

autorelease is pushing your variable in to list of pools for future releases:

```
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
// your code
self.label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];
// your code
[pool release];
```

Then you don't need to call

```
[self.label release];
```

because variable is autoreleased. And in code line

```
[pool release];
```

will released at succesfully.

This is for leak skirting

Answer (score 0):

Self.label is a property.

UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] -> retain count is 1

self.label = tempLabel -> retain count now is 2

But you only use self.label, So if you don't use autorelease or release the label that you created, you will get memory leak issue ;)